# ¿Qué significa «En 2.° plano»?

Tags: traducción

Yo he restablecido mi iPhone hoy, y estoy restaurando la configuración.

En el panel de configuración de Safari, hay una opción «Abrir enlaces» que tiene dos valores posibles:

- En página nueva
- En 2.° plano

Entiendo la primera, pero no sé lo que esta última significa.

¿Qué significa «En 2.° plano» en este contexto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es lo que en inglés se dice "background". "En primer plano" es lo que aparece delante del todo.
Cuando abres la pestaña en "segundo plano", te la abrirá, pero no perderás el foco de la página en la que estás ahora, seguirás viendo la página actual.

Comment: No tengo iPhone ni he usado Safari. Muchas veces, además de lo que ponga, es mejor probar lo que hace. Esto pasa tanto en castellano como en inglés en las interfaces de los programas.

Answer (score 1):

"2°" es una abreviatura del ordinal "segundo".  Es exactamente lo mismo que "2<sup>nd</sup>" en Inglés.

Se verá también "2ᵃ" en lugar de "segunda" cuando lo que se describe es una sustantivo feminino.

Por ejemplo:

```
2° Plano   = Segundo Plano
2ᵃ Persona = Segunda Persona
```

Y para los ordinales que terminan con 'r' en la forma masculina:

```
1ʳ Plano    = Primer Plano
1ᵃ Persona  = Primera Persona
```

Comment: cuando se contrae "primer" se escribe «er» en superíndice, no solamente «r»